# How this code works to add the cache value?

Tags: asp.net

```
public static void Add<T>(T cacheObject, string keyName)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(keyName, cacheObject, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                                     TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
}
```

Hello friends I am new to asp.net my question is I have this code to Add the cache value.

my question is when i cal this methods two times.. it will have two keys? or it will overwrite previous one?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "This method will overwrite an existing
>   cache item whose key matches the key
>   parameter."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bawy15w.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It will overwrite assuming you pass in the same keyname.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the same value to `keyName`, the old value will be overwritten.

If you pass a different value, a new entry will be created in the cache.